# Node.js какую версию установить?

Tags: node.js

Всем привет! На linux mint установила Node.js версия - 8.10, потом узнала, что последняя версия 10.16.3, а как обновить версию не понятно, инф не нашла. Можно ли работать на старой версии?

Answer (score 1):

У вас в минт есть snap?
Уверен, что если не предустановлен, то можно установить через apt.

Попробуйте установить через snap.

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel=10
```

потом, если захотите перейти на новую версию, это можно сделать так

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=12
```

Answer (score 1):

Получилось установить нужную версию с помощью nvm. Ссылка с описанием: https://tecadmin.net/install-nodejs-with-nvm/

Comment: Раз уж это ответ, то стоит написать подробнее. И удалить из него благодарность, адресованную непонятно кому.

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста под другими ответами комментарий, почему они не помогли с решением и поблагодарите заодно за потраченое время.

Answer (score 0):

Работать с 8 версией для каких целей?
Для обучения вполне возможно.

Чтобы установить определенную версию ноды, сначала нужно сообщить системе, из репозитория с какой версией вы хотите качать пакет.
Для этого нужно выполнить команду:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_<КАКУЮ ХОТИТЕ ВЕРСИЮ> | sudo -E bash -
```

например

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

После этого можно устанавливать

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

или если уже установлена скажем 8 версия, можно просто обновить пакет

```
sudo apt upgrade -y nodejs
```

если потом захотите перейти на следующую версию, то обновляете запись с репозиторием и снова обновляете пакет:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt upgrade -y nodejs
```

Comment: При попытке указания репозитория с нужной версией ноды выдает ошибку:                            
 Your distribution, identified as "tina", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support.                                                                                                В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: специфичная для минт проблема. не очень хочу вникать, но похоже решение есть здесь: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/881

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Все сложно по вашей ссылке получается, с помощью nvm обновила версию без проблем.